# Replacing non-negative entries of a complex diagonal matrix with zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\Lambda_r$ be a real-valued diagonal matrix containing negative elements. We can replace the negative elements with zeros this way
$$\frac{\Lambda_r + \lvert \Lambda_r \rvert}{2}$$

Let $\Lambda_c$ be complex-valued diagonal. If at all possible, is there any equation similar to the above which will include $\lvert \Lambda_c \rvert$ in order to replace the negative entries (real entries that are negative) with zeros?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it's possible. If you wanted the same thing done to the real parts of all entries (i.e., to replace negative real parts of complex entries as well with zeroes), I can think of a way. But as it is you want an algebraic operation that (on the complex plane) affects elements on the negative real axis but leaves _everything else_ invariant. Intuitively that seems impossible.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts.